# using R's internal tar function on specific files

Tags: r, tar

R has a handy cross platform tar() function that can tar and gzip files. It seems this function was designed to tar up entire directories. I was hoping to use this function to tar and compress a subset of a directory, or a single file. I can't seem to do this, however. I was expecting the following to tar up a single csv file in the current working directory:

```
tar( "tst.tgz", "myCsv.csv", compression="gzip" )
```

So is it only possible to use the tar() function on directories?

I've temporarily gotten around this by creating a temp directory, copying my files, and then tarring the whole temp dir. But I was hoping for a bit simpler solution. That would not require copying the files which is somewhat time consuming for large files.

Comment: If you only have one file, why not use gzfile?

Comment: i really want do more... but willing to start with one

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think that is possible as you describe JD. The `files` argument is passed to the `path` argument of `list.files`, and as a result it works by tarring up files in directories, not individual files.

If you are prepared to edit an internal function, `tar()` can be made to do what you want, by fiddling with the call to `list.files()` inside `tar()`. A bit of fiddling produced the `tar2()` function below, which has extra arguments to control what `list.files()` returns. Using this function, we can achieve what you want via a call like this:

```
tar2("foo.tar", path = ".", pattern = "bar.csv", recursive = FALSE, 
     full.names = FALSE, all.files = FALSE)
```

The `all.files = FALSE` is likely redundant unless you have hidden files with names containing `"bar.csv"`.

The `recursive = FALSE` bit just stops the function searching anywhere but the current directory, which seems what you want and speeds the search up if the working dir has a lot of files and sub-folder.

The `full.names = FALSE` bit is key. If this if `TRUE`, `list.files()` returns the matched filename as `"./bar.csv"`, which `tar()` would stick in a folder inside the tarball. If we set this to `FALSE`, `list.files()` returns `"bar.csv"`, so we get a tarball with a single CSV file as requested.

If you have files with similar names and wish to only find the stated filename, peg it inside the pattern with `^` and `$`, eg:

```
tar2("foo.tar", path = ".", pattern = "^bar.csv$", recursive = FALSE, 
     full.names = FALSE, all.files = FALSE)
```

Here is the modified `tar()` function as `tar2()`:

```
tar2 <- function (tarfile, files = NULL, compression = c("none", "gzip", 
    "bzip2", "xz"), compression_level = 6, tar = Sys.getenv("tar"),
    pattern = NULL, all.files = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE) 
{
    if (is.character(tarfile)) {
        TAR <- tar
        if (nzchar(TAR) && TAR != "internal") {
            flags <- switch(match.arg(compression), none = "cf", 
                gzip = "zcf", bzip2 = "jcf", xz = "Jcf")
            cmd <- paste(TAR, flags, shQuote(tarfile), paste(shQuote(files), 
                collapse = " "))
            return(invisible(system(cmd)))
        }
        con <- switch(match.arg(compression), none = file(tarfile, 
            "wb"), gzip = gzfile(tarfile, "wb", compress = compression_level), 
            bzip2 = bzfile(tarfile, "wb", compress = compression_level), 
            xz = xzfile(tarfile, "wb", compress = compression_level))
        on.exit(close(con))
    }
    else if (inherits(tarfile, "connection")) 
        con <- tarfile
    else stop("'tarfile' must be a character string or a connection")
    files <- list.files(files, recursive = recursive, all.files = all.files, 
        full.names = full.names, pattern = pattern)
    bf <- unique(dirname(files))
    files <- c(bf[!bf %in% c(".", files)], files)
    for (f in unique(files)) {
        info <- file.info(f)
        if (is.na(info$size)) {
            warning(gettextf("file '%s' not found", f), domain = NA)
            next
        }
        header <- raw(512L)
        if (info$isdir && !grepl("/$", f)) 
            f <- paste(f, "/", sep = "")
        name <- charToRaw(f)
        if (length(name) > 100L) {
            if (length(name) > 255L) 
                stop("file path is too long")
            s <- max(which(name[1:155] == charToRaw("/")))
            if (is.infinite(s) || s + 100 < length(name)) 
                stop("file path is too long")
            warning("storing paths of more than 100 bytes is not portable:\n  ", 
                sQuote(f), domain = NA)
            prefix <- name[1:(s - 1)]
            name <- name[-(1:s)]
            header[345 + seq_along(prefix)] <- prefix
        }
        header[seq_along(name)] <- name
        header[101:107] <- charToRaw(sprintf("%07o", info$mode))
        uid <- info$uid
        if (!is.null(uid) && !is.na(uid)) 
            header[109:115] <- charToRaw(sprintf("%07o", uid))
        gid <- info$gid
        if (!is.null(gid) && !is.na(gid)) 
            header[117:123] <- charToRaw(sprintf("%07o", gid))
        size <- ifelse(info$isdir, 0, info$size)
        header[137:147] <- charToRaw(sprintf("%011o", as.integer(info$mtime)))
        if (info$isdir) 
            header[157L] <- charToRaw("5")
        else {
            lnk <- Sys.readlink(f)
            if (is.na(lnk)) 
                lnk <- ""
            header[157L] <- charToRaw(ifelse(nzchar(lnk), "2", 
                "0"))
            if (nzchar(lnk)) {
                if (length(lnk) > 100L) 
                  stop("linked path is too long")
                header[157L + seq_len(nchar(lnk))] <- charToRaw(lnk)
                size <- 0
            }
        }
        header[125:135] <- charToRaw(sprintf("%011o", as.integer(size)))
        header[258:262] <- charToRaw("ustar")
        header[264:265] <- charToRaw("0")
        s <- info$uname
        if (!is.null(s) && !is.na(s)) {
            ns <- nchar(s, "b")
            header[265L + (1:ns)] <- charToRaw(s)
        }
        s <- info$grname
        if (!is.null(s) && !is.na(s)) {
            ns <- nchar(s, "b")
            header[297L + (1:ns)] <- charToRaw(s)
        }
        header[149:156] <- charToRaw(" ")
        checksum <- sum(as.integer(header))%%2^24
        header[149:154] <- charToRaw(sprintf("%06o", as.integer(checksum)))
        header[155L] <- as.raw(0L)
        writeBin(header, con)
        if (info$isdir || nzchar(lnk)) 
            next
        inf <- file(f, "rb")
        for (i in seq_len(ceiling(info$size/512L))) {
            block <- readBin(inf, "raw", 512L)
            writeBin(block, con)
            if ((n <- length(block)) < 512L) 
                writeBin(raw(512L - n), con)
        }
        close(inf)
    }
    block <- raw(512L)
    writeBin(block, con)
    writeBin(block, con)
    invisible(0L)
}
```

Comment: I got the feeling I was trying to make tar() do something it's not intended to do. Thanks for confirming ;)

Comment: @JD Long It can be done if you edit the `tar()` function to accept different arguments. See my updated Answer for one solution.

Comment: I'd been mulling whether to approach R-devel with a patch after looking at this. It'd make `tar()` even more useful. I'd need to do a bit more checking first before proposing it though.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson, I think it would be worthwhile submitting it but I think the interface ought to be simplified just to have a files argument and not the extra arguments that `tar` does not currently have.  These extra args make it easier to implement but are not as convenient for users.  I have given your post an upvote in any case.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck Agreed. The `tar2()` I posted was just something @JD could make use of. I'd need to think about a proposed change along the lines you mention though; `list.files()` doesn't work how we might want to use tar so it will likely need some amount of modification to avoid the extra arguments.

Answer (score 3):

This has been revised again further simplifying the `tar1` code.  Also `tar1` can now output one file without a directory or multiple files without a directory.  Essentially we need to work around a bug in the use of `list.files` by R in tar and we do that by redefining the `list.files` that `tar1` uses.

The line that manipulates the environment of `tar` actually creates a copy of `tar` whose environment is the environment within `tar1` so that when the copied `tar` is run it first looks there for `list.files`.  If we had not made a copy of `tar` with a new environment then it would have used the `list.files` in the base of R, ignoring our redefinition.

Below `tar1` is a variation of the `tar` command that produces a tar file whose components having one level (i.e. a single file or set of files without directories).  It is assumed that all files are in current directory.

Following the definition of `tar1` we test it by creating two files and creating an archive with the first of those files and then with both of those files.

```
# tar a single file
tar1 <- function(...) {
    list.files <- function(...) ..1
    environment(tar) <- environment()
    tar(...)
}

# test - first create test files, then some test runs of tar1
cat("a", file = "a.csv")
cat("b", file = "a.csv")

tar1("tst.tgz", "a.csv", "gzip")
tar1("tst2.tgz", Sys.glob("*.csv"), "gzip")
```

Comment: It works on my system. I have added the output to the post to show it.

Comment: @JD Long simplified his Q to trying to tar a single, stated csv file.

Comment: I have revised the answer as discussed in first sentence of answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll need to study the tar() function then study your answer in order to fully grasp what's going on here.

Comment: I have added some more commentary and simplified it further so hopefully its easier to understand.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Came across this elegant (seeming) answer to the same problem I'm currently having (in 2015 ...). With your proposed solution (using "bzip2")I get the following error: 
Error: object 'C_octsize' not found. What may be going on here ...?

Comment: The bug may have been fixed by now. Try `tar` directly. It seemed to work for me on Windows.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Sadly no - result is an empty (very small) file. At least on Linux. Colleagues have tried using windows and also get corrupted/not untareable results.

Comment: You may need to set the `tar=` argument of `tar`.  This worked for me on Windows:  `tar("tst.tgz", "a.csv", "gzip", tar = Sys.which("tar"))` as `tar` is on my path.

Comment: That does the trick indeed - but how portable does that code remain (I was trying with "internal" before, which doesn't work)?

Comment: I would expect that it would work on any system that has `tar` on its path.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you give `files=` the character vector it asks for, say by running `list.files()` (or its synonym `dir()`) with a suitable pattern?  Methinks the help is clear there:

> Arguments:
>
> tarfile: The pathname of the tarfile: tilde expansion (see
>             ‘path.expand’) will be performed.  Alternatively, a
>             connection that can be used for binary writes.
>
> files: A character vector offilepaths to be archived: the default
>             is to archive all files under the current directory.

Comment: yeah I should have been more verbose in my question. I started with that...Let me alter the question to the simple case of a single file, which is what I started to ask but then switched to the wildcard case mid-question.